# AEM6 repository datastore path - CRXDE asset path

Tags: aem

How to find out the CRXDE path of a certain binary stored asset (in the datastore) ? e.g.

```
/crx-quickstart/repository/repository/datastore/ff/ff/ba/ffffbaad37ed026b4e3b22ecba70088f670d36e7
```

**Background of the question:**

We create a daily backup of the AEM6 instance. This backup growed from one day to the other from around 65 GB to around 140 GB, more than double size!
Audit logs didn't tell us anything about the change.
We compared the /crx-quickstart/repository/repository/datastore folder of both days and found out that some of the datastore folders increases by more than a GB. 
All size differences in all these folders together sum up moreless to this 85 GB diff, so that matches (some minor diffs in folders outside of datastore).
Now we'd like to find out which asset relates to which folder in the datastore to know which assets caused the size increase.

Another option would be to have a good XPATH or SQL query to get all large assets that changed during that time. 
But we can not take the creation date because the assets were probably uploaded to the system per package and then the assets have the original creation date of the source environment (where we don't have access to).
But in the package manager there are NOT any packages of the date around this huge backup size increase.

Comment: Do u have separate mount point for data store ?. If there are too many revisions then your data store will start bloating. If its tar based consider data store clean up activity more regularly.

Comment: We changed now the backup mechanism to tar compaction. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/AEM_6_TarMK_Online_Compaction.html   This helped us to reduce the size of the backups by factor 10.  The original question above is (for us) currently obsolete.